# What is the point behind this covariance related code?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have been reading a book named [c# 7.0 in a Nutshell by O'REILLY](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-70-in/9781491987643/), Topic: **Variance is not Automatic**. There is an example with 2 classes, Animal and Bear in which Animal>Bear:

```
public class Animal { }
public class Bear: Animal { }
```

And also there is a class like this:

```
public class Stack<T>
{
    private int position;
    T[] data = new T[100];
    public void Push(T obj) => data[position++] = obj;
    public T Pop() => data[--position];
}
```

In continue there are 2 versions of same class:

```
public class ZooCleaner1
{
    public static void Wash(Stack<Animal> animals) { }
}
```

and:

```
public class ZooCleaner2
{
    public static void Wash<T>(Stack<T> animals) where T: Animal { }
}
```

It explains that if I try to write:

```
ZooCleaner1.Wash(bears);
ZooCleaner2.Wash(bears);
```

the first line gets a compile-time error which says that it is not able to convert `Bear` to `Animal`. But the second line is correct and works fine. As I am new to this topc, I can't Understand the diffrence betwean these 2 lines and I think they both accept `Stack<Animal>` and why do we need to use conditional generics?

Comment: The second accepts a Stack where the type in the Stack can be anything that inherits from Animal because the second method is generic.

Comment: What if `Wash` tried to call `Push`? If it was passed a `Stack<Bear>` as a `Stack<Animal>`, this call would succeed even though a stack of bears can't hold arbitrary animals. The second method specifically accepts a `Stack<Bear>` because the `T` is replaced with the specific type used.

Comment: Both methods do accept a `Stack<Animal>` but a `Stack<Bear>` is not a `Stack<Animal>` which is why the first fails to compile. If it were you would be able to add non-Bear animals to the stack e.g. `Stack<Animal> s = new Stack<Bear>(); s.Push(new Giraffe())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stack<Animal>` represents a stack of objects of any `Animal` type.
`Stack<T> where T: Animal` represents a stack of a *single* type so long as that type inherits from `Animal`.

You cannot use a `Stack<Bear>` in place of a parameter declared as `Stack<Animal>` becuse, if you *could*, then the method could push a `Fish` onto the stack of bears. When the method that is using the stack of `Bear`s pops it off of the stack, imagine the surprise when it pops off a fish!

The second method, on the other hand, is *generic*, meaning that it can accept a stack of any type, so long as that type inherits from `Animal` So if the method gets a `Stack<Bear>`, it can *only* push another `Bear` onto the stack. Trying to push a `Fish` would be a runtime error.

Comment: Doing `stack.Push(new Fish())` would be a compile time error for the generic method.  It would only be a run time error if you did a bunch of casting `stack.Push((T)(object)new Fish())`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this "covariance". [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) is generic variance. Your code only demonstrates generic constraints.

Let's see what we can do in each of the `Wash` methods. In the first `Wash` method, we can:

```
public static void Wash(Stack<Animal> animals) { 
    animals.Push(new Animal());
    Animal a = animals.Pop();
}
```

Now suppose you have a `Stack<Bear> bears;`, and you want to pass it into the first `Wash`. Do you see how this will create a contradiction if the compiler allowed you to do this? You can't actually add an `Animal` to a `Stack<Bear>`! But as far as `Wash` is concerned, adding an `Animal` is totally fine, because it only knows that it can accept a `Stack<Animal>`!

Therefore, `Stack<Bear>` is not a subtype of `Stack<Animal>`, because you cannot add `Animal`s to the former, but you can to the latter.

In the second `Wash` method, although you can pass `bears` to it, you can't add `Animal`s to ti anymore:

```
public static void Wash<T>(Stack<T> animals) where T: Animal { 
    animals.Push(new Animal()); // error
    Animal a = animals.Pop();
}
```

Because the compiler isn't sure that `Stack<T>` is a `Stack<Animal>`. It *might be*, but it also could be a `Stack<Bear>`, or a `Stack<Unicorn>` or `Stack<SomeOtherSubclassOfAnimal>`, right?